# Can I substitute marmalade for peach preserves?

Tags: substitutions, jam

I've got a recipe here for fish done with a glaze made of peach preserves that looks pretty tasty. However, some members of my household dislike peach. Citrus is a classic pairing for fish; can I swap out the preserves for a marmalade? I'm not 100% sure on the differences between the two. Or is there another substitution that would work better?

Recipe: [Ginger-peach glazed tilapia](http://www.5dollardinners.com/ginger-peach-glazed-tilapia-2/)

Comment: From reading the recipe, it appears that honey would be a good--but differently flavored--substitute for the preserves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the sweetness, marmalade has a pronounced bitter flavor that could overpower the fish. It seems that others feel the same way — there are few online recipes for fish with marmalade, and of those few, most are for salmon which has a more robust taste of its own to balance out the marmalade. Perhaps something like an apricot preserve would be more in the spirit of the original recipe?

Comment: Marmalade is (generally) made with the whole peel/pith of the orange, which is where that bitterness comes from.  (I love it myself, but I can see how it wouldn't play well with fish.)  Some sort of fruit preserve that's made only with orange juice (and maybe a little of the zest) could give the brightness of citrus without the pithy bitterness.

Answer (score -1):

The bitter flavour of marmalade will overpower the fish.

Comment: This is exactly what Joe's answer already says.